# use python re lib parsing "user define xpath" scripts

Tags: python, regex, parsing, xpath, python-re

I'm building a "xpath parsing tool" in Python for my team.
In my case, the xpath script is not the normal xpath, the syntax that user input will be in a special struct, here is an example:

**The input format will be like:** (the element can be tuple-type or normal element)

```
sig = "(xpath_1_1, xpath_1_2), (xpath_2_1, xpath_2_2), xpath_3..."
```

which is edited in excel by users

**And my goal is to parse the string into a list-type data with tuple or normal element:**

```
[(xpath_1_1, xpath_1_2), (xpath_2_1, xpath_2_2), xpath_3...]
```

Then I can input this data into my selenium to snapshot img sequentially.

**Here is one of my testing data:**

```
sig = "(//div[@style='font-family:Arial;float: left;width:930px;font-size:12px;' and ./span[contains(text(),'005930')]], //table[@id='gv_flow_krKS0 1']),//table[@id='123456'],(//div[@style='font-family:Arial;float: left;width:930px;font-size:12px;' and ./span[contains(text(),'000660')]],  //table[@id='gv_flow_krKS0 2']),//table[@id='456789']"
```

I'm wondering is there any better way to implement this func without disrupting the order of list ?

First , I think eval() func is not a good idea since it may cause some security prob.

Now I'm trying to use re lib to solve it.

However I found it's quite difficult and have no idea how to start.

Anyone can help ? Thanks~

Comment: I think you're going to have to parse this with a state machine that tracks the nesting of `( )`, `[ ]`, `" "`, and `' '`.  There's no simple regex for doing this.

Comment: yes, thanks for the keyword. It think I should start to research the tool like ANTLR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think this does what you want.  You should try some different test strings.

```
sig = "(//div[@style='font-family:Arial;float: left;width:930px;font-size:12px;' and ./span[contains(text(),'005930')]], //table[@id='gv_flow_krKS0 1']),//table[@id='123456'],(//div[@style='font-family:Arial;float: left;width:930px;font-size:12px;' and ./span[contains(text(),'000660')]],  //table[@id='gv_flow_krKS0 2']),//table[@id='456789']"


gather = ''
element = []
elements = []
state = ''
for c in sig:
    if state:
        gather += c
        if c == state:
            state = ''
        continue

    if c == '(':
        in_tuple = True
        continue
    elif c == ')':
        in_tuple = False
        element.append( gather )
        gather = ''
        elements.append(tuple(element))
        element = []
        continue
    elif c == ',':
        if in_tuple:
            element.append( gather )
        else:
            elements.append( gather )
        gather = ''
        continue
    elif c == '[':
        state = ']'
    elif c == "'":
        state = "'"

    gather += c

# Handle leftover.
if element:
    elements.append( element )

for e in elements:
    print( e )
```

Output:

```
("//div[@style='font-family:Arial;float: left;width:930px;font-size:12px;' and ./span[contains(text(),'005930')]]", " //table[@id='gv_flow_krKS0 1']")
//table[@id='123456']
("//div[@style='font-family:Arial;float: left;width:930px;font-size:12px;' and ./span[contains(text(),'000660')]]", "  //table[@id='gv_flow_krKS0 2']")
```

Comment: Thanks
But in testing data, if I use `ast.literal_eval(sig)` , it will print Syntax Error since the param in xpath (like `//table[@id='123']`) will cause the prob.

Comment: Ah, looking at your data, of course it will.  I'm going to delete this answer.

Comment: @Time Roberts
Thanks, this is really cool, I will follow this idea and try myself :)
But I just found that the output seems lost one element.

Comment: Ah, you're right, if it's not part of a tuple it will be left over.  I need to handle any leftover.  I'll fix it.